# Управление DNS на уровне конфига

Tags: c#, сеть, dns, config, hosts

Есть задача для конкретного приложения сделать "особое" преобразование имен в адреса по сравнению с операционной системой. Персональный DNS/hosts, расположенный внутри себя. 
Есть ли возможность на уровне конфига управлять тем, как приложение разрешает сетевые имена?

Comment: Вы это конкретное приложение сами разрабатываете, или, как тут часто бывает - досталось в наследство, поделать ничего не можем, изобретаем костыли...?

Comment: сам разрабатываю. Но нужно не трогая настроек ОС (DNS, HOSTS) научиться работать с HTTPS серевром, который не готов принимать в URL IP вместо имени, и которого нет в DNS при этом